# XmlReader - Read Current Node as string

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xmlreader

In the following snippet, using XmlReader, when I encounter an element. I would like to read it as-is, including all attributes and namespace decoration in the element. Using the oXml.Name property, I am only able to get the tag name. Is there a function to get the tag itself?

```
oXml = XmlReader.Create(path, oXmlSettings)
While oXml.Read()
   Select Case oXml.NodeType
      Case XmlNodeType.Element
        'Read Element as-is
         If taglist.contains(oXml.Name)
           stringbuilder.Append(oXml.ReadOuterXml())
         End If
      Case XmlNodeType.Text
         stringbuilder.Append(oXml.Value)
   End Select
End While
```

I have tried oXml.ReadOuterXml() but it returns the element and its subcontent. That could be acceptable, but how do I fast forward my XmlReader to ignore subsequent XmlNodeType.Text and XmlNodeType.EndElement that will happen when the element I just got from ReadOuterXml has been parsed?

UPDATED: For the following snippet, loc1 is in taglist, so is written using ReadOuterXml, but the parser fails to get the following "!" character.

```
<para>
  Test blabla <loc1 href="test">complicated</loc1>!
</para>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I wouldn't expect that you'd have to fast forward the reader after calling ReadOuterXml. I'd expect the act of reading the outer XML to consume it.

Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes it does fast forward, but I believe it misses the event next after the EndElement. Is it because I already did oXml.Read()?

Comment: Are you calling Read again *after* ReadOuterXml? If so, that's the call which is hurting you.

Comment: Please see the updated code snippet, I believe Read is effectively called after?

Comment: You're going round the loop again, so yes, it will call Read again. Look at the current node immediately after calling ReadOuterXml.